# Stop eclipse formatter from removing certain useful parts of HTML code

Tags: html

```
<tr ng-repeat="rows in CalendarBean.weekList">
    <td ng-repeat="cellList in rows">
        <div id="{{cellList.fullDate}}" ng-click="onDateSelect(cellList.fullDate)" 
         class=" {{cellList.timeClass}} {{cellList.leaveFlag}}+{{cellList.holidayFlag}}" 
         style="border:{{cellList.borderColor}};  background-color: {{cellList.ColorCode}}" 
         align='center'>
            <div class="row">
                <span style="color: {{cellList.dateNumberColor}}" class="class1">
                  {{cellList.date}}
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I have this code.

```
background-color: {{cellList.ColorCode}}
```

this part and some closing second braces are getting removed while I am formatting my code in eclipse Luna. Any suggestion how to stop this?

Comment: `ng-style="{'border': cellList.borderColor; 'background-color': cellList.ColorCode}"` try this

Comment: Thank you. This worked. I just had to use comma, instead of semicolon.